# What was Hydra's plan for dealing with The Hulk?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*;

> It is revealed that Agent Sitwell is a double agent for Hydra, who is then interrogated on rooftop by Captain America, Black Widow and The Falcon.

This character then proceeds to explain what Hydra's overall plan is;

> Which is to target and murder individuals which may pose a threat to Hydra's new world order, either now or in the future. In the interogation scene, Bruce "The Hulk" Banner is specifically mentioned by name as one of Hydra's targets, as is Dr Stephen Strange. We also see later than Tony Stark is listed as one of the targets when the INSIGHT helicarriers are booting up.

However, we know very well that The Hulk is more than a little difficult to stop when he gets angry, and we also know from *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* that;

> Bullets are not enough to kill The Hulk, which is revealed when Bruce Banner talks about how he attempted to take his own life, only for the "other guy" to spit the bullet out.

Is there any point in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* or any related film-canon material (tie-in comics, TV shows, other films etc) that we find out why Hydra thought that the INSIGHT helicarriers would be able to take on The Hulk, or if they had another plan for dealing with him?

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, but the answer accepted on the original question doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: if it doesn't answer it, why mark it as a dupe yourself? just edit this and explain what's not being covered.

Comment: @phantom42 Because the questions themselves are near identical. I thought the content of the question, not the desired answer, made it a duplicate?

Comment: dupes are based on the question or existing answers (regardless of the specific question). but if the other answers don't cover what it is you are looking for, you're more than welcome to edit this one to distance it from the original question so it's not a dupe anymore, if it's necessary.

Comment: @phantom42 I think I'll leave it - I can't imagine that there is an in-universe, canon answer anyway.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's a difference between the handgun bullets Bruce tried (which the 'other guy' spit out) and the larger guns on the helicarriers.  Those guns could punch through the helicarriers.

Comment: @Jeff Well The Hulk can punch through Helicarriers too - see *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*.